# MySQL query didn't show right result

Tags: mysql

I want to specify the departments which have >=3 employees, print out the list of departments’ employees right after each department.

I have 2 tables:

```
Employee_Table (Employee_Number, Employee_Name, Department_Number)
Department (Department_Number, Department_Name)
```

This is my SQL code:

```
SELECT  ET.Department_Number,ET.Employee_Name
FROM dbo.Employee_Table ET
GROUP BY ET.Department_Number,ET.Employee_Name
HAVING COUNT(ET.Department_Number) >= 3
```

but nothing shows up if I run:

```
SELECT  ET.Department_Number
FROM dbo.Employee_Table ET
GROUP BY ET.Department_Number
HAVING COUNT(ET.Department_Number) >= 3
```

I have a right result which is 101 and 105 but combine with Employee_Name I can't get the right result.

Comment: Well, what exactly do you want to be received in the `ET.Employee_Name` column(i.e., in what form, cause it should be some kind of aggregated data, otherwise you should join received `select` with the table to get `Employee_Name`)?

Comment: remove the "having count" and see what shows up when you group by employee name

Comment: Are you looking for MySQL or Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: i typed my (sql querry) , not  MySQL , don't know why it turn into MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  
ET.Department_Number,
ET.Employee_Name
FROM Employee_Table ET
WHERE Department_Number IN
(   SELECT Department_Number
    FROM Employee_Table
    GROUP by Department_Number
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
)
```

Comment: It worked ! Thank you so much :)) , i stuck on this part like 2 hours :D

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, I would use a [CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and a JOIN.

```
WITH Departments AS (
  SELECT  ET.Department_Number
  FROM dbo.Employee_Table ET
  GROUP BY ET.Department_Number
  HAVING COUNT(ET.Department_Number) >= 3
)

SELECT D.Department_Number, ET.Employee_Name
FROM dbo.Employee_Table ET
JOIN Departments ON ET.Department_Number = D.Department_Number
ORDER BY D.Department_Number
```

How's that look?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you need a subquery to get departments having a count of 3 or more employees. This should do the trick:

```
SELECT  
ET.Department_Number,
ET.Employee_Name
FROM dbo.Employee_Table ET
join
(   Select department_number, count(department_number)
    from dbo.Employee_Table
    group by department_number
    HAVING COUNT(Department_Number) >= 3
) dept_having_3
on et.department_number = dept_having_3.department_number
```